# Prisma db push error when removing column that has a default value

Tags: prisma, prisma2

After removing a column from schema.prisma, and running `npm prisma db push`, I'm getting the error...

```
Error: The object 'users_role_df' is dependent on column 'role'.
```

I'm using Prisma `3.3.0` with the sqlserver connection.

The model looks like this...

```
model User {
    id ....
    name ...
    role String @default("USER")
}
```

I see the initial push created the CONSTRAINT `users_role_df` but now when I remove it from the model, and run push, it's not handling removing the constraint first and then the column.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the command `npx prisma migrate dev --create-only` to see what the generated SQL looks like for the migration.

You could manually add a `DROP CONSTRAINT users_role_df;` inside the generated migration or change the order of the SQL commands (if such a command already exists in the generated migration).

It is fine for you to make changes to the migration file as long as you do it before *applying* the migration to your database.

Comment: That's a good idea. I ran the command with `--create-only` and it still gave me the same error. However it created the migration and I can now add the `DROP CONSTRAINT` script. It still doesn't make sense that prisma doesn't automatically add that script to columns that have default values.

Comment: This might be a bug. Would you kindly consider creating a [bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) in the Prisma docs? If you provide the steps to replicate the problem, we will look into it.